# VBA for Excel: Count Unique Elemens comparing to another column of Duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working on a solution that count me the distance of a column of Unique Values and if you guys could help me i'd be really thankful beacause i am new with the programming.

I have done a copy paste from a sheet to another sheet and ( Column A as a list of cables and Column B the distance needed for that cable. Then, i clean the Blank Cells putting instead a 0. After that, I've eliminate the 0 in the 3 Column.

IN the third column i have develop some code to give me the list of Unique Values present on the Column 1.

My next objective it is to create a count of the unique values (Column 3) comparing them with the Column 1. If the cable X appears more than one time in the Column 1 their distance must be incremented in the first line of the Column 4 (Count Column). If not it is going to be added in the second row, etc...etc..etc..

Could you guys help me with the code? Im gonna leave a version of my code. 
Thanks!

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long, LastRow2 As Long, LastRow3 As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range
Dim a As Range, b As Range, c As Range
Dim x As Integer, contagem As String

For j = 1 To 1432

'limpar células em branco acrescentando 0 às células sem valor na distância   
Next j
  For Each a In Range("A1:A1432").Cells
     If a.Value = "" Then a.Value = 0
  Next a
  For Each b In Range("B1:B1432").Cells
    If b.Value = "" Then b.Value = 0
    Next b
Range("B1:B1432").Select
For Each c In Selection
    If Not c.HasFormula And Not IsEmpty(c) Then c = Val(c)
Next c

'Eliminar o valor 0 da coluna D

Set sh = Folha4
LastRow = sh.Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow2 = sh.Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow3 = sh.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Cells(i, 4).Value <> "0" Then
        Cells(counter + 1, 4).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next i

With ActiveSheet
    .Range("D1", .Range("D1").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End With

Set items = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = 1 To LastRow3
        If Not items.exists(sh.Range("A" & i).Value) Then
        items.Add sh.Range("A" & i).Value, i
            For x = 1 To LastRow
                If sh.Range("d" & x).Value = sh.Range("A" & i).Value Then
                sh.Range("e" & x).Value = sh.Range("b" & x)
                x = sh.Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                End If
            Next x
        Else
            For x = 1 To LastRow
                If sh.Range("d" & x).Value = sh.Range("A" & i).Value Then
                sh.Range("e" & x).Value = sh.Range("b" & x).Value + items(sh.Range("a" & i).Value)
                End If
            Next x
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You have a column that lists the unique values?

Comment: If yes, then just `NumberOfUniqueValues = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count`, being "C" the name of the column with the unique values

Comment: Yes i have a column with the Unique Elements. First column it is the copy from another sheet , second column distance of the cables and the third column the unique values